# CSS: having issues with 100% width in chrome

Tags: css

Here is my site: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/331982/Sandbox/comsat.html

To get the items to appear that are messing up the 100% width: click two hexagons and have your browser maximized.

`#playerTwo`, the right hand section, has a large chunk appearing off the right side of the browser i.e. scrollbars appear.

I know there are some issues with percentage widths in browsers, and one of the solutions I found was setting the margin and padding to 0px, but it didn't help.

*The reason why I'm using percentages, is because I plan on eventually making the page responsive. =\

Comment: I'm trying hard to understand what you want here and I can't

Comment: notice how there is a scroll bar? I don't want that to appear due to my elements not being confined to the width of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have `width:500px` on `#playerone, #playertwo`, and `width: 40%` on `.nameslider`, and you don't have `position:relative` on `#playerTwo`, so it's width is calculated from the documents' width.

So to fix it you can try to add `position:relative;overflow:hidden;` to `#playerone, #playertwo` and set the `width` for `.nameslider` to `100%`.

Or maybe just experiment a little more — there are a lot of things to improve in your markup :)